# UIPageControl-like effect in a one infinite row Collection View

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I'm building an app where I'd like let the user pick between places in a restaurant. Here's the interface so far.

[image]

I'd like to swipe on that row with several choices so that the user can see more than three choices. And I'd like to get the nice effect like UIPageControl where you swipe and stop at the right exact position so that the UI looks always like above.

I figured out there were maybe two solutions :

- Using the UIPageControl BUT is it possible to remove the little dots at the bottom ?
- Using UICollectionView BUT :

  - Is it possible to stop at the exact position like UIPageControl ?
  - Is it possible to have an infinite horizontal scrolling instead of the default vertical one ?

Thank you for your help and ideas !

Comment: You can use [TKScroller](https://github.com/virus108/TKScroller). Lib for that,

Comment: I have looked at it but it's not exactly what I meant.Thanks though !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use UIScrollview and add these three or more view as subviews as dynamically.

In scrollview's property check 'paging enabled'.So it scroll like pageControl.You can use UIScrollView's delegate method,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

for change images or subview.

EDIT :

Answer is cool ! Thanks. Just to complete the answer : these two tutorials :
http://sketchytech.blogspot.fr/2012/04/unlocking-magic-of-uiscrollview.html
http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html